# Ionic storage Error missing dependencies: @angular/core

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic4, ionic-storage

I followed [this](https://devdactic.com/ionic-4-image-upload-storage/) tutorial to install ionic camera in ionic project, but when I run ionic serve command I am getting this error:

> [ng] ERROR in The target entry-point "@ionic/storage" has missing
> dependencies: [ng]  - @angular/core

and in browser on localhost:8100 I can see only "Cannot GET /" ERROR

How to fix this error so I can see my home page preview in browser

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem. Try exclude the folder (into your project) *node_modules* and then execute (into de same folder of the project) *npm install*. It's worked for me.