# Ionic storage-angular error: Can't resolve '@angular/common' in storage-angular/fesm

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic3, ionic5, ionic-storage

I'm trying to use `ionic/storage-angular` in my ionic application. I was following the documentation: https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-storage.

I installed storage-angular (`npm install @ionic/storage-angular`) but I'm getting this error when importing `IonicStorageModule` in my app.module:

> ../../node_modules/@ionic/storage-angular/fesm2020/ionic-storage-angular.mjs:2:0-51
> Error: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@angular/common' in '/home/<path_to_my_project>/node_modules/@ionic/storage-angular/fesm2020'

In app.module.ts I just did:

```
import { IonicStorageModule } from '@ionic/storage-angular';

imports: [ ... IonicStorageModule.forRoot()]
```

I'm using this version:

```
   Ionic CLI                     : 7.2.0 (/home/baffo/.nvm/versions/node/v20.11.0/lib/node_modules/@ionic/cli)
   Ionic Framework               : @ionic/angular 7.6.6
   @angular-devkit/build-angular : 17.1.1
   @angular-devkit/schematics    : 17.1.1
   @angular/cli                  : 17.1.1
   @ionic/angular-toolkit        : 9.0.0
```

I tried this solution, but didn't work: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64717548/10946588

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I don't know how exactly I fixed it but:

- I have a couple of warning complaining about 'CommonJS or AMD dependencies' so I added this to the `angular.json` (following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62592903/upgrading-to-angular-10-fix-commonjs-or-amd-dependencies-can-cause-optimizatio) solution):

```
"projects": {
"app": {
"build": {
"options": {
"allowedCommonJsDependencies": [
"rxjs-compat",
"localforage"
],
```

- I revert all the changes of `package.json` and `package.json.lock` and removed `node_module` folder.
- Then, I reinstalled everything again:

```
    npm install 
    npm install --save @ionic/storage
    npm install --save @ionic/storage-angular
```

And it's working now.